# Function declaration syntax in Go

Tags: function, syntax, go

What is (c App) in the following function declaration?

```
func (c App) SaveSettings(setting string) revel.Result {
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
func                                                      Keyword to define a function
     (c App)                                              ????
             SaveSettings                                 Function name
                         (setting string)                 Function arguments
                                          revel.Result    Return type
```

Comment: Instead of asking such questions I'd suggest skimming the short  and easy to find [Go Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations). IMO, questions and answers that do nothing more than just regurgitate parts of a readily available and more authoritative source aren't useful.

Comment: 1) I wouldn't say that document is short at all.
2) I already looked at that document, but I was looking at function declarations, not method declarations, because I know nothing about Go: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations
3) Actually everything can be found in more authoritative sources.

I think this question may be of use to future people learning Go, and perfectly fits on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ivan, agreed, I was looking at Function_declarations too!  And the doc isn't short.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`(c App)` gives the name and type of the *receiver*, Go's equivalent of C++ or JavaScript's `this` or Python's `self`. `c` is the receiver's name here, since [in Go it's conventional to use a short, context-sensitive name instead of something generic like `this`](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments#Receiver_Names). See http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations --

> A method is a function with a receiver. The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceeding the method name.

and its example:

```
func (p *Point) Length() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y)
}
```